# Citrix 2monitors extended screen = ok, but can't get apps to maximise on only one screen?

Tags: citrix

I have Citrix virtual desktop extended over to screens but when I open an application I want to maximise it on only one screen.
I did have it working as required but for some reason it's stopped and I can't figure out what I did before to get it to work.

Help much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Search please, as I helped on such question before, its a known citrix problem. Iam just too lazy to search the site to find the duplicate, in the mobile its hell to search & flag as a duplicate

Comment: I've searched again but when narrowing with search tags it comes up with answers to extending over two screens which is not my problem.